# Python variable inside of function not able to be called

Tags: python, function, variables

I am making an rpg type thing with python and I made a few functions but I need to call variables that were stated and altered inside of a separate function. How would I be able to call a variable inside a function.
My Code:

```
import time
def title():
  print("Hello Welcome To Elvoria")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Choose Your Gender, Name, And Race")
  time.sleep(1)
def gnd():
  Gender = input("""Male, Female, Or NonBinary?
""")

  if Gender == ("Male"):
    genderin = 'Male'
  elif Gender == ("Female"):
    genderin = 'Male'
  elif Gender == ("NonBinary"):
    genderin = 'Male'
  else:
    gnd()
def nm():
  namein = input("""What Is Your Character's Name?
""")
  print("Welcome To Elvoria "+namein+"")
def rac():
  print("""The Race Options Are:
Elf-Good With Archery And Light Armor
Kelner-Good With Two Handed Weapons And Heavy Armor
Human-Good With Bows And Stealth
Mageine-Good With Magic And Speed""")
  time.sleep(1)
  racin = input("""Now Choose A Race
""")
  if racin == ("Elf"):
    print ("You Are Now A " + genderin + racin +" Named" + namein + "")
  elif racin == ("Kelner"):
    print ("You Are Now A " + genderin + racin +" Named" + namein + "")
  elif racin == ("Human"):
    print ("You Are Now A " + genderin + racin +" Named" + namein + "")
  elif racin == ("Magein"):
    print ("You Are Now A " + genderin + racin +" Named" + namein + "")
  else:
    print ("You Are Now A " + genderin + racin +" Named" + namein + "")
title()
time.sleep(1)
gnd()
time.sleep(1)
nm()
time.sleep(1)
rac()
```

And The Error Code:

```
   print ("You Are Now A " + genderin + racin +" Named" + namein + "")
NameError: name 'genderin' is not defined
```

Comment: This isn't how functions are supposed to be used.  In particular, don't have `gnd` call itself, and use parameters and return values to have them communicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your functions to `return` the result, and take the values they need as parameters:

```
def gnd() -> str:
    gender = input("""Male, Female, Or NonBinary?
""")
    if gender in ("Male", "Female", "NonBinary"):
        return gender
    return gnd()

def nm() -> str:
    name = input("""What Is Your Character's Name?
""")
    print(f"Welcome To Elvoria {name}")
    return name

def rac(gender: str, name: str) -> str:
  print("""The Race Options Are:
Elf-Good With Archery And Light Armor
Kelner-Good With Two Handed Weapons And Heavy Armor
Human-Good With Bows And Stealth
Mageine-Good With Magic And Speed""")
    time.sleep(1)
    race = input("""Now Choose A Race
""")
    print (f"You Are Now A {gender} {race} Named {name}")
    return race
```

When you call them, make sure to assign the values to variables so you can use them again:

```
title()
time.sleep(1)
gender = gnd()
time.sleep(1)
name = nm()
time.sleep(1)
race = rac(gender, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- You could create a global variable, and define that using the global  statement in your function, so you can use the global value afterwards
- You could pass a value to the function, and work with it (the better way, using global variables should be avoided)